# C# WPF - Binding Dictionary to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

#### Scenario

- Lets say I use C# WPF, and bind a Dictionary() to a DataGrids datasource.
- When I update the dictionary will the DataGrid automatically update and refresh?
- Also, will the DataGrid lose focus whilst doing this?
- In the event that updating the dictionary does not update the datagrid, how would I go about implementing this?

Help Greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the datagrid will not update if you use a normal dictionary.  Your data structure must notify the world when an item in it changes for it to update the grid. the grid will not, normally, lose focus.  Check out [Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/) for a nice article on this.

What you need is a dictionary that will pass item updates (not when an item is added/removed).